# expected value of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-interpretation

Take two random variables $X=a+bX_0$ and $Y=c+dY_0$, and define $T=X-Y=\mu+\sigma Z$ where $\mu$ is the mean of $T$, $\sigma$ its standard deviation and $Z$ is a standardized random variable with mean $zero$, unit variance and continuous PDF $\phi$ and continuous and increasing CDF $\Phi$. NB: $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

What does $\Phi(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma})$ mean, either in terms of $T$?  or $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

It represents the probability that $T$ is less than $0$ or equivalently the probability that $X$ is less than $Y$.

$$\text{Prob}(T \le 0) = \text{Prob}(\mu+\sigma Z \le 0)=\text{Prob}(Z \le \frac{-\mu}{\sigma})=\Phi(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma})$$

Comment: That is correct, and I appreciate it. $\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$ is the inverse of the Coefficient of Variation. I was eager to know if that expression give a special meaning to my CDF.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Phi(-\mu/\sigma)=P(Z\leqslant-\mu/\sigma)=P(\sigma Z+\mu\leqslant0)=P(X\leqslant Y)$$